# Datatables.net throwing TS2339 error with isDataTables on TS 2.3.4

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables

Running Angular 2, Typescript 2.3.4, Node 6.10.3, with datatables.net:

```
├── @types/jquery.datatables@1.10.36
├── datatables.net@2.1.1
├── datatables.net-buttons@1.3.1
├── datatables.net-buttons-zf@1.3.1
├── datatables.net-responsive@2.1.1
├── datatables.net-responsive-zf@2.1.1
├── datatables.net-zf@2.1.1
```

The `toggleTable` code started throwing TS2339:

`error TS2339: Property 'isDataTable' does not exist on type '{ (param?: ResponsiveDataTablesSettings): DataTable; (param?: Settings): DataTable; }'.`

```
toggleTable() {
    if (! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#sample-table')) {
        this.setupSampleTable();
    }
    this.table = !this.table;
}
```

The relevant section of `node_modules/@types/jquery.datatables/index.d.ts` is:

```
interface JQuery {
    DataTable(param?: DataTables.Settings): DataTables.DataTable;
}

export interface StaticFunctions {
    /**
    * Check is a table node is a DataTable or not
    *
    * @param table Selector string for table
    */
    isDataTable(table: string): boolean;
```

How do I fix the type on `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0):

Just add  in front of it:
if (($.fn.DataTable).isDataTable('#sample-table')) {